# xslt add title to column name

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Hey  i have a problem.

```
 <xsl:variable name="x" select="'MY_TITLE'"/>
```

I need to add title to column in table but title which i want to add is variable (x) and i dont know how to deal with it.

```
 <table border="1">
      <xsl:variable name="items" select="$xsd//xs:complexType[@name = 'ONDType']/node()/attribute::*[1]"/>
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <xsl:for-each select="$items">
          <td title='$x'>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
```

If i run this code i get title $x but i want to get MY_TITLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<td title="{$x}">
```

To understand how it works, read up on [attribute value templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#attribute-value-templates).